# Child object of variable in state does not display

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Im trying to print data from a parent object in react. This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class Wallet extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            wallets: [],
            updates: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        var jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/wallet', {
                token: jwt,
                walletid: this.props.match.params.walletid
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({wallets : response.data.data});
                console.log(this.state);
        });
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <h1>{this.state.wallets['name']}</h1>
                <div className="wallets">
                <table className="classic">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Wallet</th>
                                <th>Balance</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>

                                <td>{this.state.wallets.wallet_updates.xxx}- he</td>
                                </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Wallet
```

I have no idea why, but whenever I call wallet_updates.xxx it says cannot call xxx of undefined, even though I have checked, and it definitely exists in the state. I have also tried putting the specific child object in another state object however that does not seem to work either.

Comment: Not sure why you are calling `this.setState()` twice in your `componentDidMount()`. Also, you noted  in your local state that `wallets`is an array but you are accessing a property called `wallet_update` which I don;t think is what you want to do

Comment: My bad, was a later version of the code, forgot to simply just put it all in one setstate statement, still doesnt work without that line though =/

Comment: Your state sets up arrays, but you are setting properties on them like they are objects.

Comment: Yea I agree. Your `wallet` state is an array. So maybe you want to make it consistent between your `state` and the what you are doing in your `this.setState()`

Comment: I dont know how I missed something so stupid, ive been trying to fix this all day, thank you so much lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens on the first render I suspect, your state tree is not correct.
You've set your state to be Arrays but you're working with the as if they were Objects.

Here, `this.state.wallets.wallet_updates.xxx`, is indeed undefined.

A better approach would be to create a more representative initial state.

```
this.state = {
    wallets: { name: 'n/a', wallet_updates: {} },
    updates: []
};
```

This will help you hunt down further bugs since it's more in line with what you're trying to do with your `setState`s.

Comment: Cheers man got it working! Cant believe I missed it. - will mark as solution when I Can